# Remove the border from a selected cell in a row in datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

As you can see in the picture around Jesse Furher is a black border line, how can i remove that line for all cells?

[image: example]

Comment: Does my answer works for you or still looking for something else?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add this style in your DataGrid Resources and the selection border will be gone -

```
<DataGrid>
  .
  .
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
      <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
  .
  .
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/> has no effect - you can leave it out. Setter for BorderThickness is the key to success.

Comment: @pr)gg3r - `FocusVisualStyle` is needed in case you put focus via Tab key. In that case you will see dotted border around your cell.

Comment: The cells will be very tight when removing that border. How can the spacing be increased again? Setting `Padding` or `Margin` doesn't help.

Comment: @LonelyPixel: for each `DataGrid*Column`, set the `ElementStyle` to a `<Style TargetType="TextBlock"><Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/></Style>` (or whatever).